# Как заменить файлы в билде

Tags: cmake, cmakelists

Недавно начал пользоваться CMake. Есть проект, который зависит от некоторых текстовых док-ов. Использую команду для копировки:

```
add_custom_command( TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} POST_BUILD
                COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory
                ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/dir_to_copy $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${PROJECT_NAME}>/dir_to_copy )
```

Но есть проблемы, эта команда не заменят эти файлы в билд директории. То есть, если старые версий файлов существуют, то просто пропускают. Поэтому приходится вручную удалять `dir_to_copy` с билд директории, тогда cmake правильно скопирует. Возможно ли дописать команду, которая сперва проверит одинаковые ли файлы, типа `SOURCE_FILE == DESTINATION_FILE` и если нет, то заменить.

Comment: `cmake -E copy_if_different` не помогает?

Comment: @Fat-Zer не помогло, но спасибо за ответ

Comment: @RoarRaizZer всмысле не помогло? Покажите как вы прописали эту команду, что делали и каков результат

Comment: @Fat-Zer заменил `copy_directory` на `copy_if_different`. Эффекта нет, но если удалить файлы(которые нужно скопировать) с `DESTINATION_FOLDER`, то не скопируются вообще файлы

Comment: @RoarRaizZer, `copy_if_different` копирует только файлы... список файлов можно создать предварительно с помощью `file(GLOB_RECURSE ...)`, но тогда из минусов — при добавлении новых файлов они не будут копироваться до следующего запуска `cmake`...

Comment: @Fat-Zer спасибо вам. Я попробую и сообщу, получится.